# Aligning a doubly wrapped nested flex

Tags: css, flexbox, gallery, margin

I am trying to build a responsive gallery with images and accompanying text descriptions. Images and their text should sit side-by-side on the same row, unless the width is too small and everything is collapsed to a single column. My only issue is that in the single column mode, **I would like the images to be aligned on their left to the wider text**. Everything else is perfectly aligned and centered as I want.

I understand that flex is not supposed to do what I want, and I tried replacing the inner flex with a grid, but could not make it work. I would be happy to learn both about the easiest way to fix this (preferably without media queries), and more generally, what would be the correct approach to this. Most importantly, I would not like to be required to introduce new arbitrary numbers, other than the width of the image, and of the text element, and the given gaps. I would have guessed that such a design would be a common enough use case, but apparently lacking the correct terminology, I could not find reference implementations.

https://jsfiddle.net/tj13y7sc

**Edit:** The most promising directions seem to me:

1. For an easy fix: Giving the image the same width as the text, and using a negative(?) margin to fix the horizontal gap when they are on the same row.
2. For the right way to do it: Replacing the inner flex with a grid - but i could not got it to not collapse all the time.

**4 columns - good:**
[image: 4 columns - good]

**2 columns - good:**
[image: 2 columns - good]

**1 column - misaligned:**
[image: 1 column - misaligned]

```css
.flex_container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
  gap:64px 128px;
}

.flex_container_item {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
  gap:64px;
}

.text {width:360px;}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="flex_container_item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" width=256>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>description1</h1>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex_container_item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" width=256>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>description2</h1>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="flex_container_item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" width=256>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>description3</h1>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex_container_item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" width=256>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>description4</h1>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by me!

1. Wrap the img with a div named "image".
2. Set div "image" width to 360px (same as text) - this will fix single column mode, but now the gutter is too large by 360-256=104px.
3. To fix this we add to both image and text divs: `margin: 0 -52px;` - this will fix the gutter by -52*2=-104, while keeping everything symmetric.
4. Finally we add `margin: 0 52px;` to .flex_container_item, to cancel out the effect the previous step on the outer margins.

https://jsfiddle.net/yt0pfnje/

Takeaways:

1. Never give up. Never surrender. I am ashamed to admit how many hours I've put into this. But hey, now I know how to use flex, grid and margins.
2. This would have been so much easier if gap could take negative values. Can anybody help suggest this to the spec?
3. I still could not make it work with grid. I believe it is not possible due to the way auto-fill works
4. CSS is broken. It should not be so difficult. It should not take so long to solve. The other attempted answers were suggested by first-class web experts who could still not get it right. I now believe there is no simpler way. But there should be.

Comment: Hey I Have check your solution your solutions is not working for mobile screen it gives scroll. my code is working perfect for every device screen. I share ScreenShot for code view. here are the links.

Your Code View: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/703467645139419197/789735697837457408/screencapture-file-D-StackOverFlow-demo-html-2020-12-19-11_34_19.png


My Code View: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/703467645139419197/789735723846729768/screencapture-file-D-StackOverFlow-demo-html-2020-12-19-11_34_48.png

Comment: your solution by giving margin -104 is not as perfect as mine.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful remarks. You bring up some good points which i did not consider in my problem definition, and which you seem to solve as well. Indeed my initial approach breaks below 360px by design, as i am using fixed width elements up to 360px. Moreover, the negative margin approach in my accepted answer prevents an easy fix as you've suggested using max-width. However, width<360 is not really a scenario i care about, and my answer does solve my fundamental question of the alignment issue, and doing so without using media queries as asked for.

Comment: please note that my answer has been repeatedly edited against my will. you can read my original one here: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65365617/4

Answer (score 2):

Just change the second class justify-content to "left" as:

```
.flex_container_item {
      display:flex;
      flex-wrap:wrap;
      justify-content:left;
      gap:64px;
    }
```

[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WU7T.png) (not allowed to upload images here yet..)

Comment: this makes everything left justified. but the texts should be centered.

Answer (score 1):

Your width of img and div container of text are different, try keeping it same and it will be properly align.

Or if you want that specific width of text container.
Then use media query and change flex-direction to column for smaller screens.

[image: by using media query and changing flex-direction]

Comment: indeed the image should be thinner than the text

Comment: then you can use media query for smaller screen and change the flex-direction for smaller size.

`
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .flex_container_item {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
} 
`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/flex-box-align-issue-n6t6o?file=/index.css

Check this by resizing the window or by zooming out

Comment: what is the  calculation to get 600px? 600 does not seem to cover all cases. i get a single column before the media query kicks in

Comment: That's just the value I provided for example, provide the value as per your design.
Check the breaking point when it transition to single column and provide that value.

Comment: i am afraid that due to subtle differences between browsers one number may not suit all. of course i can always take a max() of these, but it seems exhausting and hacky that i would need to manually test multiple browsers to set this value. there must be a better way (and preferably without media queries)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like adding the next condition might do the trick -

```
.flex_container_item img {
  border: 1px solid blue; /* just for test */
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

see here: https://codepen.io/elicohenator/pen/MWjpgze

Comment: this aligns the image to the left of the window, while i want it to be aligned to the left side of the (centered) text.

Comment: Well it would be very hard to do it since the text has a constant width and the image not...

Comment: the image has a constant width of 256

Comment: Hmm well the layout is not usual, but you can look at the updated codepen here: https://codepen.io/elicohenator/pen/MWjpgze

Comment: this changes the gap when the image and text are on the same row, and moreover gives a strange layout in some other cases - see: https://imgur.com/a/RgwsIMM

Answer (score 1):

Now I just wanting to know you that I bind `<img>` in a `<div class="image"> </div>` and then make some CSS changes, and also add a media query for the responsiveness.

I also add comments in CSS file what I have make change.

The following is the code snippet that you want.

```css
.flex_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 64px 128px;
}

.flex_container_item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 64px;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  /*value change*/
  max-width: 360px;
  /*new property add*/
}


/*new code added*/


/*use 720px media width because we have to fix .image class width same as we have already set for .text class so that they align at the same edge. so now total width for both the blocks is 360px + 360px = 720px.*/

@media(max-width: 720px) {
  .image {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 360px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="flex_container_item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" width=256>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>description1</h1>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex_container_item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" width=256>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>description2</h1>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex_container_item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" width=256>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>description3</h1>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex_container_item">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" width=256>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>description4</h1>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @eyaler did you check this answer, does it works for you?

Comment: seems to work, although i am still not sure why it should be 720px

Comment: use 720px media width because we have to fix `.image` class width same as we have already set for `.text` class so the width of both the classes are same 360px, so now both the box content align at the same edge. so now total width for both the blocks is `.image` class width 360px + `.text` class width 360px = total width 720px.

Answer (score 0):

surround the `<img>` tag with a div as such:

```
  <div class="flex_container">
      <div class="flex_container_item">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" width=256>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
.
.
.
```

and add to the css:

```
    .image {
      width:360px
    }
```

like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/860c4tfj/

Comment: this changes the gap between the image and the text in the cases that they are on the same row. as mentioned before, my issue is a result of having different widths for the image and text

Comment: it may have been able to solve it with a negative gap. but seems that negative gaps are not a thing

Comment: may be with negative margins?